# PHP Regular Expression to find @someone

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need a regular in expression in PHP that I can plug into preg_match_all and find if an @ sign and any character number or letter follows right after that.

So if I put

> @patrick hello there

it will come up true, if I put in

> "I saw her @ the mall"

it will be false.

Thank you

Comment: hello there! Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An at sign followed by at least one letter, number, or underscore:

```
/@\w+/
```

Answer (score 0):

Great site on Regex: http://www.regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

as well as http://www.regular-expressions.info/ as the fellow below me pointed out!